# Gitian building not working

Tags: bitcoin-core, compiling, gitian

I followed this instructions https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/gitian-building.md
but on this step: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/gitian-building.md#setting-up-the-gitian-image
i have got an error:

> cp: cannot stat
>   ‘base-trusty-amd64-bootstrap/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lxc/lxc-init’:
>   No such file or directory debian@debian:~/gitian-builder$

How to fix it?

Comment: install 64 bit libraries

Comment: Commenting from far in the future for anyone coming across this today. Bitcoin Core now [uses Guix](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/db720b5a703c90625fa7a4773bd2db5672427cbe/contrib/guix/README.md) for bootstrappable builds. [This gist](https://gist.github.com/hebasto/7293726cbfcd0b58e1cfd5418316cee3) shows the practical workflow.

Answer (score 0):

you have to make sure you are using AMD64 version of debian jesse

Answer (score 0):

Gitian has a couple of different virtualization modes, each with their own quirks and issues. It appears that you are using LXC, which in my experience, no longer works.

You could try the same commands with KVM mode (drop `--lxc` and don't set `USE_LXC=1`) or docker mode (use `--docker` instead of `--lxc` and set `USE_DOCKER=1` instead of `USE_LXC`). I have found that the docker mode is much more reliable since all of the setup for the container is handled by other projects.

For building older releases, you may need to slightly modify gitian-builder to use different apt package sources as Ubuntu moves them to their archival locations.

---

For building more recent versions of Bitcoin Core, Gitian has been replaced with Guix. But it's still useful for those who are interested in building older versions of the software.